# DeltaLake merge columns with null values

Tags: apache-spark, merge, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I am using DeltaLake API to update rows in a table using the code below

```java
DeltaTable.forPath(sparkSession, cleanDataPath)
          .as("target")
          .merge(df.as("source"), "target.desk_mirror_name = source.desk_mirror_name AND target.price = source.price AND target.valuationdate = source.valuationdate AND target.valuationversion = source.valuationversion")
          .whenMatched()
          .updateAll()
          .whenNotMatched()
          .insertAll()
          .execute();
```

This should match all the columns between source and target tables, except for column `valuationtag`

Before merge, the target table is like the following

```
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|desk_mirror_name| price|valuationdate|valuationversion|valuationtag|
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|          Sample|499.97|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|210611170317|
|          Sample|967.93|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|210611170317|
|          Sample| 500.0|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|210611170317|
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
```

The source table (that should update the target table) is as follows

```
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|desk_mirror_name| price|valuationdate|valuationversion|valuationtag|
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|          Sample|499.97|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|    OFFICIAL|
|          Sample| 500.0|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|    OFFICIAL|
|          Sample|967.93|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|    OFFICIAL|
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
```

Only `valuationtag` is changed into *OFFICIAL*. Having this, the updated table is

```
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|desk_mirror_name| price|valuationdate|valuationversion|valuationtag|
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|          Sample|499.97|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|    OFFICIAL|
|          Sample| 500.0|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|    OFFICIAL|
|          Sample|967.93|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|    OFFICIAL|
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
```

So far so good.

The problem starts when a column (in both tables) contains **null** values. Let's say that column `desk_mirror_name` is changed to nulls in the target table

```
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|desk_mirror_name| price|valuationdate|valuationversion|valuationtag|
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|            null|499.97|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|210611170317|
|            null|967.93|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|210611170317|
|            null| 500.0|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|210611170317|
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
```

With a source table having exactly the same data, except for `valuationtag` being changed into *OFFICIAL*, the updated table, strangely, have new lines inserted, instead of being merged. The result is the following

```
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|desk_mirror_name| price|valuationdate|valuationversion|valuationtag|
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|            null|499.97|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|210611170317|
|            null|967.93|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|210611170317|
|            null| 500.0|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|210611170317|
|            null|967.93|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|    OFFICIAL|
|            null| 500.0|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|    OFFICIAL|
|            null|499.97|   2021-06-10|    210611170317|    OFFICIAL|
+----------------+------+-------------+----------------+------------+
```

It seems that DeltaLake did not correctly handle `desk_mirror_name`, which is having null values, both in the source and target tables.

How to deal with such a specific situation ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is expected behavioral in spark. Apache Spark supports the standard comparison operators such as `>, >=, =, < and <=.` The result of these operators is unknown or `NULL` when one of the operands or both the operands are unknown or `NULL`. In order to compare the NULL values for equality, Spark provides a null-safe equal operator `(<=>)`, which returns False when one of the operand is NULL and returns True when both the operands are NULL. Ref [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-null-semantics.html#comp-operators).

As this reason , `Null` is being considered as `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clauses can only have the `INSERT` action. The new row is generated based on the specified column and corresponding expressions. All the columns in the target table do not need to be specified. For unspecified target columns, `NULL` is inserted.

Answer (score 4):

Using Null-safe equal operator <=> instead of = should solve this problem.
I have tried it in Databricks SQL notebook and it works fine.
[Spark SQL NULL Semantics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-null-semantics.html#comp-operators)