# How does null works in SAS and in DataBricks?

Tags: null, sas, databricks-sql

I know that null is not blank space or zero. But it seems to have a difference between SAS null and DataBricks null. I'm doing the same queries in both softwares. First I create a column using a case clause. I gave it four opitions:

`CASE ... WHEN CASE...  WHEN THEN 'x' ELSE 'y' END THEN 'z' ELSE ''  END` 
So, in my head I have x, y, z and '' as rows. But... in SAS:

`PROC SQL;  SELECT COUNT(column) AS TOTAL FROM TEMP.table WHERE column IS NOT NULL ;`

Returns 2280

`PROC SQL;  SELECT COUNT(column) AS TOTAL FROM TEMP.table WHERE column IN ('x', 'y', 'z') ;`

Returns 940

AND WHAT GOT ME:

`PROC SQL;  SELECT COUNT(column) AS TOTAL FROM TEMP.table WHERE column IN ('x', 'y', 'z', '') ;`

Also returns 940.

When I was writting the query, I thought '' would be null (I'm new at SQL). But if using in ('x','y','z','') and ('x','y','z') gets the same number of rows, in my head, therefore, there aren't any '' rows. So, what is these 1340 rows that are not null?

In DataBricks things get more and more confusing. Using the same tables, and comparing the number of lines with SAS, all matches until I try counting using null:

`spark.sql(""" SELECT  column FROM table WHERE column IS NOT NULL """).count()`
Returns 1539629!!!!

`spark.sql(""" SELECT  column FROM table WHERE column IN ('x','y','z','') """).count()`
Also return 1539629, which means that '' is not null in Databricks.

If I do:
`spark.sql(""" SELECT  column FROM table WHERE column IN ('x','y','z') """).count()`
I get 1530 rows. More than SAS!

When I compare the entire table in SAS and DataBricks they have the same number of rows, 1539629. But... what's happening when I try to get only ('x','y','z') rows?

I told my friend what was happening and he replied me "SAS doesn't make sense, you should use MISSING instead of NULL, IS NOT NULL doesn't work". I read a little bit of this https://comp.soft-sys.sas.narkive.com/Bk1FCcik/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-missing-in-proc-sql but still, I don't undersant what's happenig.

I tried a new thing. I was confused about sas, so I runned the following query:

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT 
column, 
COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM table
group by column
```

Which resulted in something that made sense and are correct. I made the same with DataBricks. So, my conclusion is that there're something off with the way I made de column. I'll put the code here:

SAS:

```sql
1. CASE 
2.          WHEN b_old <> 'in' AND b_in = 'in' 
3.          THEN 
4.              CASE
5.                  WHEN date_b BETWEEN &fst_day. AND &last_day.
6.                  THEN 'x'
7.                  ELSE 'y'
8.              END
9.          WHEN b_old = 'in' AND b_in <> 'in' AND 
10.                 date_b &fst_day. AND &last_day.
11.                 THEN 'z' 
12.             ELSE ''
13. END AS xyz
```

DataBricks:

```sql
1. CASE
2.     WHEN b_old != 'in' AND b_in = 'in' 
3.     THEN CASE
4.         WHEN date_b BETWEEN date_format(DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(month, -1, LAST_DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())))),'yyyy-MM-dd') AND date_format(LAST_DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())),'yyyy-MM-dd') 
5.         THEN 'x'
6.         ELSE 'y'
7.     END
8.     WHEN b_old = 'in' AND b_in != 'in' AND date_b BETWEEN date_format(DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(month, -1, LAST_DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())))), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND date_format(LAST_DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
9.     THEN 'z' 
10.    ELSE 'N/A'
11. END AS xyz
```

Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: Run PROC FREQ on your COLUMN variable with / MISSING option to see how many observations there are for each value of COLUMN including any observations where the values are blanks.   Is DATABRICKS the actual database you are using or just a user interface to some other database? If the later what database are you using.

Comment: Databricks null handling here . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100523/deltalake-merge-columns-with-null-values/69756588#69756588

Comment: @Tom I runned a query that counted and gruped the results, x, y, z summed up to 2280 in sas and 1530 in databricks. Both have different databases, but they are equal, I tested counting the lines. So I think the problem is how I made the column that has x, y and z as rows

Comment: You seem to have some random numbers inserted into the code.  Are those line numbers that did not get removed in copying?

Comment: I would be very careful using things like `<>` or `!=` as operators as different languages might interpret them as meaning different things.  For example in normal SAS syntax , like data steps and PROC steps,  `<>` is a MAX operator not the NOT EQUAL operator that it is in SQL code.

Comment: You are probably being tripped up by the TRI level logic in databricks.  If B_OLD is NULL then it is neither equal to 'in' nor not equal to 'in'.  So you need to make sure to include that possibility in designing your CASE clauses.

Comment: @tom I corrected, no more random number, I didn't see it before :). The b_old and b_in have null, '', 'in' and four other options, I don't think the error is that. But I'm looking into de <> begin MAX, when I writted I thought <> =! were exchangeable. You've being helping me a lot, thank you!

Comment: In many databases you can have variable length character variables. So null, an empty string, a string with only one space and one with two spaces are all different values.

Comment: @Tom, now both are equal! The error was in using b_old != 'in' (and b_in != 'in'), if b_old = null it did not worked, you said that, but I didn't get how could null not be different from 'in'. Anyways, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

SAS does not have a NULL. But it does understand MISSING values.

For a character variable it will treat a value that only contains spaces (SAS uses only fixed length character variables padded with spaces) as MISSING.  For numeric variables SAS has 28 missing values.  The regular missing value represented in code by `.` and 27 special missing values `.A` to `.Z` and `._`.

SAS does not do the TRI level logic that most database systems use these days.  Boolean expressions are either TRUE or FALSE.  Two blank strings are equal to each other and do not equal any other strings.  `.` is equal to `.`, but not equal to any number or any special missing value.